# Discord.js 12.5.1 Error: Cannot find module './GuildTemplate'

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am developing a discord bot and hosting on Heroku. Everything has been going well, but I just updated discord.js to 12.5.1 today. After pushing to heroku, I get this error:

[image]

I didn't change any code, just updated djs and pushed.